# Reading an XML file into an R table

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I have data in a specialized XML file called HML. The file is very large, containing data on hundreds of samples, and has a structure that looks like this (first several lines of the file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.nmdp.org/spec/hml/1.0.1  http://schemas.nmdp.org/spec/hml/1.0.1/hml-1.0.1.xsd" version="1.0.1" project-name="NGS_low_res_TruSight_NGSengine" xmlns="http://schemas.nmdp.org/spec/hml/1.0.1">
  <hmlid root="2.16.840.1.113883.19.3.999.5" />
  <reporting-center reporting-center-id="UPABRO" />
  <sample id="19-45678-HLA-072319AB" center-code="UPABRO">
    <collection-method>unknown</collection-method>
    <typing gene-family="HLA" date="2022-08-03">
      <allele-assignment date="2022-06-13" allele-db="IMGT/HLA" allele-version="3.47.0">
        <glstring>HLA-A*02:01:01:01+HLA-A*29:02:01:01</glstring>
```

The data I am interested in getting out is the sample id (line 5) and the glstring (last line), although there are several lines of glstring in each sample.

I have used the `xml2` package to read the file:

```
library(xml2)
test <- read_xml("test.hml")
xml_children(test)
```

Which gives the following output:

```
{xml_nodeset (386)}
 [1] <hmlid root="2.16.840.1.113883.19.3.999.5"/>
 [2] <reporting-center reporting-center-id="UPABRO"/>
 [3] <sample id="19-45678-HLA-072319AB" center-code="UPABRO">\n  <collection-m ...
 [4] <sample id="19-45679-HLA-011620-AB-NGS" center-code="UPABRO">\n  <collect ...
 [5] <sample id="19-45680-HLA-080819-AB-NGS" center-code="UPABRO">\n  <collect ...
```

The individual samples that I'm interested in obviously start at child 3. However, I cannot find a way to start extracting data at child 3, and then only extracting certain nodes in each child.

Comment: you probably need `xml2::xml_find_all()` to select all sample-nodes, and then `xml2::xml_attr()` to extract the text from the relevant attributes.

Comment: Thanks, @Wimpel, this is getting me closer. I was able to extract sample numbers with the following code: `(bar <- test
  %>% xml_find_all( "//d1:sample")
  %>% xml_attr("id")
  %>% as_tibble
  )`

Comment: To get the glstring, I have tried this code: `(bar2 <- test
  %>% xml_find_all( "//d1:sample")
  %>% xml_find_all( "//d1:glstring"))` which gets me closer: `{xml_nodeset (3611)}
 [1] <glstring>HLA-A*02:01:01:01+HLA-A*29:02:01:01</glstring>
 [2] <glstring>HLA-B*44:03:01:01/HLA-B*44:03:01:04/HLA-B*44:03:01:10/HLA-B*44: ...` Using `xml_attr` doesn't work to get the string after glstring out, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the glstring is the contents of the node and not the attribute, use the `xml_text()` function to retrieve the node's value.

```
library(xml2)
library(dplr)

bar2 <- test   %>% 
   xml_find_all( "//d1:sample")   %>% 
   xml_find_all( ".//d1:glstring"))  %>% xml_text()
```

Most likely since you mention that there are multiple glstrings per sample ID.  You will need to loop through all of the sample IDs and extract out the glstrings for each sample.

This example code should work (I have not tested since the xml sample above was not a complete sample ID)

```
samples <-  test   %>% 
   xml_find_all( ".//d1:sample")

dfs <- lapply(samples, function(node){
   #get sample ID 
   sampleID <- node %>% xml_attr("id")
   #get glstrings 
   glstring <- node %>%  xml_find_all( ".//d1:glstring"))  %>% xml_text()

   data.frame(sampleID, glstring)
})
answer <-bind_rows(dfs)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you so much! I added some code to the end to get the glstring results arranged per sample.

Comment: The final code: `test <- read_xml("test.hml")

samples <-  test   %>% 
   xml_find_all( ".//d1:sample")

dfs <- lapply(samples, function(node){
   #get sample ID 
   sampleID <- node %>% xml_attr("id")
   #get glstrings 
   glstring <- node %>%  xml_find_all( ".//d1:glstring")  %>% xml_text()

   data.frame(sampleID, glstring)
})

(answer <-bind_rows(dfs)
  %>% mutate(locus = str_extract(glstring, "HLA-[:alnum:]+"))
  %>% pivot_wider(names_from = locus, values_from = glstring)
 )`